# How do i make svcutil create a client from a service whose service-contract is part of an external Class library?

Tags: .net, wcf

I'm hosting a wcf service (.NET 4.0) on IIS. The service class implements interface `Interface_A` which holds the  [ServiceContract] and [OperationContract] attributes. Everything is alright when `Interface_A` is part of the wcf project. But when `Interface_A` is in another project ( my service contracts project), `svcutil` creates the `.config` file only whereas no `.cs` file is created. I don't get any error and `wsdl` looks same in both scenarios.
I'm using svcutil against wsdl.
I think having the service interfaces in its own project is a very realistic scenario as it allows a strict seperation between service interfaces and service implementation.

Comment: can you share your svcutil command line?

Comment: **svcutil /ct:System.Collections.Generic.List`1 /a /reference:" path\Data.Contracts.dll" /reference:" path\Service.Contracts.dll" /reference:" http://127.0.0.1/Service.svc /config:client /out:client /n:*, Service.Clients** ,  **Note:** Reference to Data.Contracts.dll which contains the classes containing the  [DataContract] attributes is working fine, only the ref Service.Contracts.dll (=[ServiceContract]) seems to cause problems.

Comment: why not just use: svcutil /out:Test_Client.cs /ct:System.Collections.Generic.List`1 /a http://127.0.0.1/Service.svc

Comment: The /reference parameter allows me to use the same dll's on service and on client's side.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my mistake: It seems that there is no good reason to have `[servicecontract]` in a seperate dll. So it's ok to have `[servicecontract]` in the wcf service class and the service class implements `Interface_A` which is in a seperate dll. Clients and other services might use this interface to provide a common architecture.